# idea springboot run on ssh, dev-tools doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I create multi springboot modules in idea,and each module is run on ssh,then the springboot dev-tools doesn't work.

But if I only create one springboot project and run it on ssh,the springboot dev-tools can take effect after I edit a java file.

Sorry ,my English sucks.I don't know if you can understand what I wrote.

Thanks for your help!

[one server in project,dev-tool will take effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZkk.png)

[multi module in project,dev-tool won't take effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR7jV.png)

Comment: Devtools might cause classloading issues, in particular in multi-module projects. [Diagnosing Classloading Issues](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.diagnosing-classloading-issues) explains how to diagnose and solve them.

Comment: See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools